# Getting configuration from dts file on x86 system

Tags: linux-kernel, grub2, grub, x86, device-tree

There is a requirement in a project where we have to take certain configuration values of a device from device tree.

I was able to generate device tree blob (`.dtb`) from `.dts` file. There is apparently a GRUB command called `devicetree` using which we can pass the device tree blob to kernel and use APIs present in `<linux/of.h>` to extract the parameters.

But whenever I use the command `devicetree` in GRUB command line, I am getting an error saying "command not found". The command is not present in the list when I enter `help` but present in [GRUB manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/devicetree.html).

What I am doing wrong here? What is the procedure to use device trees in GRUB on x86 system?

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of grub.  I ran into a similar situation a few years ago.  Turned out the grub docs were for version 2.02 while the version in our software (Wind River Linux 8) was version 2.00 and was missing features we wanted to use.  We ended up building grub from source to get version 2.02 into our builds.